# How to find selected li from drop down and points on range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, range, html-lists

Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/21/). I'm trying to add scores together from options to get a result. I'm stumped on how to assign each different type of radiation a score (not sure if my current way is correct) and how to implement the drop-down menu options into the java-script too. Pretty sure the whole thing could be fixed by this one line:

```
 var $selectedValues = $('#amount, .dropdown').find('input:selected, option:selected');
```

but I also need to know how to assign different scores to all the different points on the range of radiation

I really hope this makes sense. If not, I hope my jsfiddle clears things up. Thank you so much for any help

I would also like to point out that hardly any of the javascript is actually mine because I am so juvenile at it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$('body').on('click', '#evaluate', function(e) {`

***Change:-***

```
var $selectedValues = $('#amount, .dropdown').find('input:selected, option:selected');
var selectedValues = [];
$selectedValues.each(function(k, v) {
   var $selected = $(v);
   selectedValues.push($selected.val());
});
```

***To***

```
var amount = $('#amount').val();
var dropdown = $.trim($('.wrapper-dropdown-1').children('span').text().split(':')[1]);
var selectedValues = [amount,dropdown];
```

Working example:-https://jsfiddle.net/8ns65z9f/